# how to send data through javascript to cakephp controller action so that audio file save in the temp folder

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

here is add.ctp file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.add_audio').click(function(){  
    var sFileaudio = document.getElementById("audio").value;
    if(sFileaudio =="")
      {
        alert("plz add an audio file");
      }
    var sFileExtension = sFileaudio.split('.')sFileaudio.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
    var iFileSize =  document.getElementById("audio").files[0].size;
    var iConvert = (iFileSize / 4194304).toFixed(2);
    if(sFileExtension != "mp3" || iFileSize > 4194304)
      { /// 4 mb                                 
        var div = "Error : plz choose mp3 format and below then 5 mb " ;       
        var result = div.fontcolor("red");
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML =  result;
      }
    else
      { 
        var div = "Sucess File " ;       
        var result = div.fontcolor("green");
        document.getElementById("color").innerHTML =  result;
        var formdata = $("#form-validation").serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->html->url(array('controller' => 'teachers','action' => 'upload'),true); ?>' ,
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata, 
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
        alert(data);
        }
       });
        }  
       });                                                   
 });
</script>
```

Bascically i just want to save an audio file to the temp folder through javascript/ajax code.

below is the field and button in add.ctp file.

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-4">
    <?php echo __('Audio'); ?>
    <span class="red_dot">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-8">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input("audio" ,array('type' => 'file','id'=>'audio','label' => false,'div' => false,'data-validation-type'=>'present'))?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-4">
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-8" id="color">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-4">
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-8"><input type="button" class="add_audio"  value="Upload" id="add" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

here what i get in pr($this->request->data); controller through script

```
Array
    (
    [Teacher] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [email] => 
            [password] => 
            [location] => 
            [subject] => 
            [dob] => 
            [biodata] => 
            [status] => 1
        )
```

)

So in this list the image and audio fields of Teacher is missing. How would i add that?
i am very new to cakephp and javascripts also. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set the url of the ajax call to the action you are looking for, comething like `baseUrl + /controller/action`. Also, what version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Thanks for reply ,Cake version is 1.0, as you suggested its not working, data did not gone to the controller...

Comment: finally its done with use of ajaxupload.js script :-)